# Can't a non-primary column be use as a bound column in MS Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, combobox

I have the following profile table in my db:

```
Number | LastName | Year
1      | Kim      | 2015
2      | Song     | 2018
3      | Park     | 2015
4      | Ahn      | 2015
```

What im trying to display is list of names in year 2015, for example. The output will display names "Kim, Park and Ahn".
I have a form with the combobox and the subform of a datasheet. Whenever I clicked a year in the combobox, the names in the datasheet will change.
During creating the combobox, i use the "Find a record on my form based on the value I selected in my combobox". I used the column year that will appear on my combobox.

When i check the row source of the combobox, the query goes like this:

```
SELECT number, year
FROM profile;
```

Since, the year 2015 appeared 3 times, i need to group it. But i cannot group it if the primary key 'number' is included in the select sql. So therefore, i removed it and set the bound column to the year. However, it will not work.
Does that mean, ms access support only primary keys?

Comment: if i did not delete the 'number' in the query and set the bound column to year, still it wont work. It will only work if the bound column is set to the primary key

Comment: i also wanted to group the 'year' column as it is necessary since there are duplicated values in the combobox. And if i group it, i need to omit the primary column.

Comment: Control used just for selection of filter criteria should be UNBOUND (no ControlSource). Then `SELECT DISTINCT [year] FROM profile;` You should edit your question with the additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select one arbitrary row only for each year:

```
SELECT 
    First(number), 
    year
FROM 
    profile
GROUP By
    year
```

Comment: I think the `number` field should not be needed.

Comment: but the number field is what is used to fetch data into my datasheet. if i set my bound column to the year field without having the number field, it wont fetch data.

Comment: but your query does it. how come it is group by?

Comment: As you want unique years, you have to select only one number for each year. That can be done with First(), Last(), Min(), or Max().